# Re-render component content in Vue Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I made a 'read more' component in Vue Js and when the text passed via props changes, the component doesn't re-render showing the new content.

That's the component's code:

```
Vue.component('readmore', {
    template: 
            `
            <span>
                {{ part1 }}<span v-if="leia.mais">...
                    <span class="text-info ml-2" style="cursor:pointer;" v-on:click="readMore"> Leia mais</span>
                </span><span v-if="!leia.mais">{{ part2 }}
                    <span class="text-info ml-2" style="cursor:pointer;" v-if="leia.menos"  v-on:click="readLess">Leia menos</span>
                </span>
            </span>
            `,
    data: function () {
        return {
            part1: '',
            part2: '',
            leia: {},
            defaultMaxChr: 200
        }
    },
    
    props: ['maxchr', 'text'],

    created: function () {
        var text = this.text;
        var maxchr = this.maxchr ? this.maxchr : this.defaultMaxChr;
        if ((undefined === text) || (0 === text.length)) {
            console.warn('COMPONENTE LEIA MAIS: Parâmetro text indefinido ou foi passada uma string vazia.');
            return;
        }

        if (text.length <= maxchr) {
            this.part1 = text;
            this.part2 = '';

            this.leia = {mais: false, menos: false};
        } else {
            this.part1 = text.substr(0, maxchr);
            this.part2 = text.substr(maxchr);

            this.leia = {mais: true, menos: false};
        }
    },
    methods: {
        readMore: function()
        {
            this.leia.mais = false;
            this.leia.menos = true;
        },

        readLess: function()
        {
            this.leia.mais = true;
            this.leia.menos = false;
        },

    },

});
```

If I have the code below and change the input, nothing happen.

<readmore> and <input> are inside another component, which defines text in its data attribute.

```
<input v-model="text">

<readmore
    v-bind:text="text"
    v-bind:maxchr="100"
></readmore>
```

Comment: move all code which is in `created`, into a method called `init` or such, then add a watcher which watches `text`, then recall init, or go the computed way.. issue is created is called when its created, not when a prop changes

Answer (score 0):

That's because you execute your logic inside the `created` function which will only be executed once on the component's initial load. and will not execute again when the `text` prop change, you need to use `watch` with immediate execution to check changes on text.

```
watch: {
  text: {
    handler() {
        var text = this.text;
        var maxchr = this.maxchr ? this.maxchr : this.defaultMaxChr;
        if ((undefined === text) || (0 === text.length)) {
            console.warn('COMPONENTE LEIA MAIS: Parâmetro text indefinido ou foi passada uma string vazia.');
            return;
        }

        if (text.length <= maxchr) {
            this.part1 = text;
            this.part2 = '';

            this.leia = {mais: false, menos: false};
        } else {
            this.part1 = text.substr(0, maxchr);
            this.part2 = text.substr(maxchr);

            this.leia = {mais: true, menos: false};
        }
    },
    immediate: true
  }
}
```